# Compatible HDD issue

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I recently fired up an old, retired PC I own running Windows 7. It's a [HP Pavilion a1629.uk](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-a1629-uk-tower-pentium-d-820-2-8-ghz-2-gb-200-gb/) and although it came with a 200Gb HDD I upgraded them to two 400Gb HDD's at some stage. The replacements were [these, both identical](https://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=HITACHI%20HDT725040VLA380) and although it worked surprisingly well when I booted it up one of them was giving signs of imminent failure. As I had a spare 1TB HDD lying around - this [Seagate model](https://www.cnet.com/products/seagate-desktop-hdd-st1000dm003-hard-drive-1-tb-sata-6gb-s-st1000dm00325blk/) - I threw it in for one of the 400GB's drives but given it was noticably different in appearance to the others I didn't have a lot of confidence that it would be compatible and sure enough, when I booted it up it didn't recognise the drive at all.

I could probably revert to the two 400GB drives for what I want to do with it but to make it worth my while digging it up I want to replace the drives with a bigger one so my question is two fold -

1. Given the specs that are listed for the existing and new drive from the links I've posted, is there a clear reason why it wouldn't recognise the new one.
2. What compatible drives could I upgrade to given what I had already installed?

Comment: Compatible or read? Was the 1tb store bought and otherwise a virgin unpartitioned drive?

Comment: The 1TB drive was a brand new drive, it's never been used before and although I've had it a while it was unopened as it was on delivery.

Comment: What does "didn't recognise the drive at all mean"? If you go into BIOS can it detect the model?

Comment: I went into BIOS and given that it was the only drive installed there were no drives listed.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the system without the 1 tb drive to start with and open a partion manager of your preference and create a partition table on the 1 tb, best to use a 'gpt' table on something of that size.  Then you can reintroduce the 1 tb back to the system with a formatted partition(s) to suit your environment.

Comment: Ok, I'll to give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: Most folks are unawares to the fact generic drives sold at (insert PC/electronic store here) come with NO partition table hence are purpose and OS agnostic.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm not up to speed on HDD's so I appreciate the help.